# How to work with resources in Java 9 modules

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, java-module

I built a small (hello world style) java 9 project using gradle and the [jigsaw plugin](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#step_4_use_the_code_experimental_jigsaw_code_plugin_to_do_the_same_thing).

For a junit test I tried to access some file as a resource, but `classLoader.getResource(filename)` is not able to locate the file.

Usually you put the file as `src/test/resources/foo.txt` and access it as `/foo.txt`, but with Java 9 it looks like things changed and resources are (similar like classes) [encapsulated  in modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Where exactly do I have to put the resource file for gradle to package it correctly?

What is the right way to access that file afterwards in the test?

What is the documentation I forgot to read? :)

---

To be more precise I set up a small [test project](https://github.com/michas2/java_9_resource_test).
Use `git clone https://github.com/michas2/java_9_resource_test.git` and do a `gradle build` afterwards after changing to that directory. (I'm using gradle 4.6, but that should not be the problem.)

The structure looks like this:

```
.
├── build.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       ├── module-info.java
    │       └── resourceTest
    │           └── Main.java
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── resourceTest
        │       └── MainTest.java
        └── resources
            └── resourceTest
                └── test.txt
```

I try to access the resource using `this.getClass().getResource("/resourceTest/test.txt")`, which unfortunately gives `null` in return.

Comment: Package them the same way (except that resources really really should be in package-like directories—`com/example/myapplication/foo.txt`, not `/foo.txt`).  Use [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-), not ClassLoader.getResource.

Comment: I tried exactly that, but without success. [Here](https://github.com/michas2/java_9_resource_test) is what I did.

Comment: I’m not a Gradle expert, but I suspect you want to move src/test/resources to src/main/resources.  (Note that a shorter way to write this.getClass().getResource("/resourceTest/test.txt") is `this.getClass().getResource("test.txt")`.)

Comment: Well those are resources only needed for testing, so putting those in main does not make sense. I also tried with all different variations of using slash and package name, without success. feel free to test any ideas with my repository above.

Comment: Ah, right, never mind.  I confused Main with MainTest.  Are you building a .jar file and running from that?

Comment: No jar. Please do `git clone https://github.com/michas2/java_9_resource_test.git` and have a look at the output of `gradle build`.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a Gradle bug.

When I run Gradle with the `-i` option, I see that the actual command it’s executing to run your program includes this:

```
--patch-module resourceTest=/home/vgr/src/java_9_resource_test/build/classes/java/test
```

As you can see, it’s including the `build/classes` directory, but not the `build/resources` directory.

Since the build places the classes and resources in separate places, there is no way to use `--patch-module`.  The classes and resources must be together, in one file tree or one .jar file.

Whether this is a flaw in the org.gradle.java.experimental-jigsaw plugin, or Gradle itself, I’m not sure.